# setting document.cookie doing nothing

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a normal JS file which sets 2 cookies. one of the cookies set looks like:

```
document.cookie = 'user=' + hash
    + '; expires=' + new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1000*3600/* 1000ms*1hr */))
    + '; path=/';
```

But for whatever reason when I go to check the cookie it isn't set. This code is definitely being run and there is nothing else overwriting the cookie. I am using dev tools and even with the debugger paused the line after this one document.cookie still doesn't show it.

If I run that code directly in the console it shows me the constructed string as `"user=yjDnIJshyztHOzJq; expires=Mon Dec 07 2020 11:18:22 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time); path=/"` but still fails to set the cookie.

Am I just missing something simple? Is it a chrome issue? I am able to set a different cookie in the same file just fine. Is it maybe an issue with the date object or something like that? Poorly formatted string?

Edit: Just to show a little bit what I'm dealing with:
[image: screenshot of no cookie]
`club` is the other cookie from the same file I mentioned, working just fine

Edit: doing a little more experimenting, it seems that any cookie set with an expiration date doesn't hold. Obviously passed expiration dates are meant to be removed but it seems like it's treating future expiration dates as passed as well and clearing them out like you'd expect if it had passed already.

Comment: "when I go to check" — How, precisely, are you checking?

Comment: This might help [https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: 'When i go to check' means I print document.cookie in the console and its returning either an empty string or a string containing other cookies

Comment: Does the hash have a value when you set it?

Comment: Yes. You can see in the example I gave that there is a string of random characters set. My best guess is it has something to do with the time zone part of the date string?

Comment: Seems to work in Chrome for me (replaced 'hash' with an arbitrary value for testing).  Console log shows the cookie, as does application/cookies

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my dev tools. You can see that even with an arbitrary value I'm getting nothing

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple goof!

Forgot to add `.toUTCString()` to the date object, so it was using `toString` instead which had the timezone thing I suspected was the issue